# String iterator cannot find end()

Tags: c++

I have read file and stored its content inside a string. Now i want to find how many unique words the file contains.

I created a

```
map< string , int > wordCount;
```

and created a function that put content of the file inside string and add it to he map

```
  void wordCounter(){
        string content;
        file.seekg( 0, ios::end );
        content.resize( file.tellg());
        file.seekg( 0, ios::beg);
        file.read( &content[0] , content.size());
        ostringstream os;
        for( string::iterator current , next = content.begin() ;  current != content.end() || next != content.end();){
            if( *next == ' ' || *next == '\r\n'){
                wordCount[ os.str() ]++;

                while( next != content.begin() && (*next == ' ' || *next ==' \r\n')){
                    next++;
                }
                os.str(" ");
                current = next;
            }else{
                if( *next <= 'Z' && *next >='A')
                    os << char( *next - ('Z'-'z'));
                else
                    os << (*next);
                next++;
            }
        }
    }
```

But this leads to the infinite loop . It seems itrator cannot find end() of the string. Why is such thing happening? I cannot find reasonable answer. Thanks

Comment: mao? you mean map?

Comment: oh , typo , thanks

Comment: That whole operation seems over-complicated.  `string word; while(file >> word) { wordCount[word]++; }` accomplishes counting the occurrences of words in a file (though a bit more work would be needed if you want to ignore punctuation).

Comment: This is a whole lot of work just to [do this](http://ideone.com/4lBc5r)

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple bugs in the shown code.

```
for( string::iterator current , next = content.begin() ;
     current != content.end() || next != content.end();)
```

This declares `current` and `next`. `next` gets initialized to `content.begin()`. `current` is not initialized, then is compared to a value. This is undefined behavior.

```
if( *next == ' ' || *next == '\r\n'){
```

`*next` is a character, a single character. Comparing a single character to two characters, `'\r\n'`, will never work, whatever that's supposed to accomplish.

Comment: Joining two negated conditions with `||` is also suspect, as is `while( next != content.begin()`.

Comment: I was so focusing on windows that i forgot that i am comparing only one character ; however , when i omit current declaration it does works but omit the last word in the file.

Comment: Actually (and obscurely), `'\r\n'` is not two characters; it's a multicharacter literal, and it has type `int` [lex.ccon]/1. Nevertheless, the comparison is, indeed, bogus.